# Remove Currency Amount From String

Tags: c#

I want to remove all currency symbol and amount from page.

Example my string:

"This is $10,000 amount is not enough $20. But Make $200.45 profit them."

Output:

"This is  amount is not enough . But Make  profit them."

How do I remove through c# code.

If anyone can give me RegEx.

Comment: A quick search would've provided you the answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx

Comment: I know that. But I am not good in RegEx. Can I get regex?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked it in a `Regex` form:

```
var s = "This is $10,000 amount is not enough $20. But Make $200.45 profit them.";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(s, @"\$\d*,?\d*\.?\d+", string.Empty);
```

Comment: I have try this one but that only remove "$" sign not amount. I want amount and symbol too.

Comment: @keyurajmera So you just want to remove the numbers too? Could you provide a sample output?

Comment: My output should be like "This is  amount is not enough . But Make  profit them."

Comment: @keyurajmera I've adapted my post. It can be done better to include a bigger range of values.

Comment: @keyurajmera May I ask why the answer was marked as not chosen?